# What is TAG and how did it become the expected standard for frum people

Tags: technology, phone

Clearly Moses didn’t bring it down from Sinai, and yet it seems that that is the standard to the extent that from what I hear certain schools would even consider it scandalous if students parents didn’t have their phones TAGed. What is TAG? Is it a specific company? And how did it become endorsed so universally almost as a matter of religious law? Whoever it is they must enjoy a good monopoly.

Comment: Can you bring more background into your question - living in Israel, I have never heard of TAG. Is it US-specific? Is this really a question about Judaism? Or is it a sociological question about the US Jewish community?

Comment: TAG is an organisation (in theory not for profit) which advises with filtering options for technology. Getting your phone TAGged is to have a filter installed to the recommendations of the organisation. I'd say the question is on-topic to the extent that halacha may or may not require a filter

Comment: Rant? (15 characters)

Comment: @AKA thank you.

Comment: @mbloch TAG is in Israel as well in Charedi neighborhoods

Comment: TAG stands for Technology Awareness Group

Comment: All this background should go into the question. And can you make the question about Judaism? I see more of a complaint about a specific company

Answer (score 6):

Tag is a Jewish company that helps filter people’s devices in order to fight the battle against Shmirat Einayim. They have a wide array of filter options for all different types of people and backgrounds

You can view their mission statement and website here: https://tag.org/

From what I’ve heard, the rates are cheap and they’re really dedicated to making sure the filters work smoothly for you, and there’s always someone on standby if the filter accidentally blocks something kosher on your phone.

Regarding your question which I’m a little unclear of, perhaps you’ve heard about Tag in a religious community where it’s a must that phones are filtered or that families don’t have televisions and whatnot. But outside of ultra orthodox communities, no one would tell you it’s a must and no one will put you in cherem if you don’t have it. Amongst modern orthodox communities, however, it is highly encouraged as it really safeguards one from tripping up on the internet and looking at things they shouldn’t be seeing.